# Как мне вытащить id и token?

Tags: swift

```
let result = String(data: (response as! NSData) as Data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
```

Вот `print`:

```
"{\"user_id\":\"133\",\"username\":\"Anonym133\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"token\":\"ca7f06f8dbb5391d9a7d3240bde433a8e94bffe7\"}"
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial

Comment: Если я правильно прочитал строку, то она сама является json-encoded стринг, ну или к ней применён другой способ энкода, потому что кавычки тут заэскейплены. То есть сначала надо её заэнкодать как строку, а потом результат уже парсить как джейсон

Comment: могу предложить два раза пронрать через NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData, хотя я не уверен, что NSJSONSerialization может распознать строку, а не только словать или обхект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON):

```
let json = JSON.parse(result)
print(json["user_id"].intValue)
print(json["token"].stringValue)
```

Подробнее [в документации](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#usage)